# Is the nuclear force for spin-dependent or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, quantum-spin

I am confused because [in this FermiLab video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gYeLHFr2LA) they said that only the weak force depends on the spin. But [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) they say that the nuclear force is spin-dependent. Is the nuclear force spin-dependent or not?

Comment: @JOKERISWALID Your question seems quite unclear. Please clarify your specific source of video and Wikipedia article or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish between the [strong interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) that acts between quarks in a hadron and the [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) that acts between hadrons. Check which of these the Fermilab video is referring to.

Comment: @WrichikBasu My question is sample does the nuclear force depend on the spin ? for exemple does the nuclear force depend on charge ? the answer is no,  so i can deduce that the nuclear force  in independent of the nature of the nucleon .

Comment: The phrase 'the nuclear force' leaves some room for ambiguity. Depending on the context is might be the real (quark-gluon) strong interaction, the residual strong interaction (between mesons and baryons), or be used as a catchall for the weak and strong interactions in all their manifestations. The question would be improved by clarifying what is meant here ow be being explicit that the choice of language comes from the video.

Comment: All capital nicks don't look very well on the first spot.

Comment: @dmckee i am talking about the residual strong interaction

Answer (score 1):

You have slightly misunderstood the point of the video.

Imagine setting up some experiment involving interactions between particles that have a spin. Now imagine reflecting the experiment in a mirror. If you aren't told whether you are looking at the experiment or its mirror image could you tell which is which?

The point of this is that reflecting something in a mirror changes the direction of its spin i.e. if something has a right handed spin then its mirror image will have a left handed spin. Mathematically this operation of reflecting in a mirror is called a [parity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)). So if the original system and its mirror image behave the same way then the system is invariant under a parity transformation.

The video is saying that the weak force is the only one that is **not** invariant under parity transformations. If you take interactions involving the electromagnetic and strong forces then the system and its mirror image behave in the same way, so you couldn't tell which was the original and which was the mirror image. However this is not true of the weak force because the weak force only interacts with particles that have a left handed spin and antiparticles that have a right handed spin. So if you see a right handed particle/left handed antiparticle interacting via the weak force you know you must be looking at a mirror image because that never happens in real life.

So it isn't the case that EM and strong forces are not affected by spin. They are affected by spin and that is what the Wikipedia article is saying. However the EM and strong forces are not affected by swapping all the spins in a parity transformation.

Comment: Ok Thanks !!!

Can you explain to me how the strong forces is affected by spin ?